# libre office convert to pdf is not working in symfony 1.4 with IIS 8

Tags: symfony-1.4, php-7, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2, libreoffice

I use below PHP script to convert a docx file to pdf using libre office.

```
<?php
$command = 'soffice --headless --invisible --convert-to pdf C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\php\test.docx --outdir C:\inetpub\myapp\pdffiles';
exec($command);
?>
```

I run this command in a symfony 1.4 app which is hosted on an IIS server. But it does not create any pdf (also does not give any error). But this is working in Linux well.

Note :
I tried and checked the output in following ways.

1. ran the same command from the command prompt - **working**
2. ran the same command using a PHP script (not through Symfony app) -
   **working**
3. ran the same command through IIS server hosted website (not through
   Symfony app) - **working**
4. ran the same command through Symfony 1.4 app hosted on IIS server - ***not working***

My test environment is Windows Server 2012, PHP7 and IIS 8 installed.

Comment: I'm having the same problem on the IIS, local works fine. Did you get it working?

Comment: I used an additional flag `-env`. My final command was `soffice -env:UserInstallation= <sofficeTmpDirUrl> --headless --invisible --convert-to pdf C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\php\test.docx --outdir C:\inetpub\myapp\pdffiles` . It worked for me. Replace the sofficeTmpDirUrl with your one (eg:- file://tmp/soffice/loaction).

Comment: What is the contents for the temporary location? file://tmp/soffice/loaction, do I need to add any files?

Comment: No need to add anything. The tmp location will be used by libreofffice as its temporary location for the current process.

Answer (score 0):

[This works](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/182108/not-able-to-launch-soffice-within-an-application-on-the-iis-server/)
Apparently there needs to be specified `-env:UserInstallation=file:///C:\some\path`

Also, see the same solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51901973/using-libreofficesoffice-exe-as-process-start-from-code-behind-not-working-o)