# Using LibreOffice(soffice.exe) as Process.Start() from Code behind not working on IIS server

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, libreoffice

I am using LibreOffice as command line for conversion of docx to pdf. I am using below code snippet.

```
    using (Process pdfprocess = new Process())
          {
            pdfprocess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            pdfprocess.StartInfo.LoadUserProfile = true;
            pdfprocess.StartInfo.FileName = "soffice.exe";
            pdfprocess.StartInfo.Arguments = "-norestore -nofirststartwizard -headless -convert-to pdf C:\\test.docx";
            pdfprocess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\";
            pdfprocess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            pdfprocess.Start();
            if (!pdfprocess.WaitForExit(1000 * 60 * 1)) {
                pdfprocess.Kill();
            }
            pdfprocess.Close();
        }
```

Everything works fine under IISExpress or Console application. When I try to run under IIS server, it doesn't work.

I am running under `DefaultAppPool` and I have given permission to `DefaultAppPool` to access LibreOffice directory but I am not able to get result.

I don't want to change Identity to `LocalSystem` as security concerns.

How can I able to run `soffice.exe` using Process.Start() under default `ApplicationPoolIndentity`?

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean?  What error are you getting?  If you're using 32-bit LibreOffice on 64-bit windows you might also need to enable 32-bit applications on the app pool.

Comment: I am not getting any error. I can see soffice.exe in taskbar but doesn't perform conversion operation. I am using 32-bit LibreOffice on 32-bit windows.

Comment: You cannot easily fix it unless you truly hack its source code to learn how it works internally.

Comment: @BrijeshGandhi, did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and I just [found](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/182108/not-able-to-launch-soffice-within-an-application-on-the-iis-server/) solution that worked for me. When I was executing conversion under CMD console everything was working fine. But soffice.exe executed under iis app didn't work.

Although, application pool has it's own user profile directory it looks like libreoffice cannot create its files there. What I did is I created temp folder under iis www directory and gave it apppool permisions. Then I passed this location with other parameters like that: "-env:UserInstallation=file:///C:/www/temp/libreoffice"

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue. The problem was that process started, but didn't exit and give no results, any StandardError output. It was definitely a problem of permissions. So I've started procmon and it showed me, it needs access to this path:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\LibreOffice
```

Looks like similar problem here:
[Why does systemprofile need Desktop folder to open excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22459127/why-does-systemprofile-need-desktop-folder-to-open-excel-file)

So not sure what to do next from security point of view, but solution is to give access to that folder for ApplicationPoolUser.

**UPDATED:**
Looks like it works not for all documents, and even after I eliminated all ACCESS DENIED issues from Procmon for other docx file, "soffice" still stuck, and I cannot kill process from Task Manager, it gives "Access Denied" dialog. Looks like it depends on some fonts, it opens something, and because it hold it, process cannot be closed, and no more files proceed.